PyGame multipleobjects comparisons/collision detection
I was able to create the collision of 2 objects in PyGame using the calculation of Euclidian distance.

Circles created are moving on the screen, changing the coordinates based on the "gravity" or "bounce" value changing the velocity in the given direction
I'm having troubles to apply that logic to more than two objects.
I'm trying to have 1 loop going through the list of created objects
Then second nested loop is again looping through that list
In that second loop I'm trying to check the distance from one object to another
Problem is, that when there is more than 20 objects it slows down, since it has to calculate distance from 1 object to another at at once while it's running

Now, I'm not asking for the code, or solution, rather just pointing in the right direction and telling me why this approach is not good and what might be the better way.
Thank you very much!
This works for 2 created objects:
def collisionDetection(objectOne,objectTwo):
euclidianDistance = ((objectOne.x-objectTwo.x)**2+(objectOne.y-objectTwo.y)**2)**0.5
if(abs(euclidianDistance)<(objectTwo.radius+objectTwo.radius)):
        print (f"COLLISION detected: Euclidian Distance[{euclidianDistance}]")
        objectOne.x = objectTwo.x-objectTwo.radius-objectOne.radius
        objectOne.velocityX *=-1
        objectTwo.velocityX*=-1
else:
        print (f"Euclidian Distance[{euclidianDistance}]")
print(euclidianDistance)

And to have something like this, calling. Yes, the loops might not be 100 % correct, I will fix it, if the general idea is completely wrong, or not.
def dynamicObjectComparing(ballObjects):
n = len(ballObjects)
if(n>0):
    for i in range(n):
        print(f'Current [x] [y] coordinates for objects {ballObjects[i].ballNumber} are: [{ballObjects[i].x}] [{ballObjects[i].y}]')
        for x in range(i+1,n):
            collisionDetection(ballObjects[i], ballObjects[x])


Use a uniform grid.
See a duplicate question on game dev stack here

Thank you, I did not come across this one... Will check it.
